# How can I move smooth slowly a Canvas Child?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this structure in the hierarchy:

The object Save Slots is a Canvas :
[image]
I can't move the Canvas and I don't want to change the Canvas Render Mode so I'm trying to move the Canvas Child:

The Child is a Scroll View ui and on the Scroll View I attached a script name Move Scroll View.
[image]
This is the script :

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class MoveScrollView : MonoBehaviour
    {
        float seconds;
        Vector3 begin;
        Vector3 end;
        Vector3 difference;
    
        void Start()
        {
            seconds = 50;
    
            begin = transform.localPosition;
            end = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            difference = end - begin;
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            transform.localPosition += difference * Time.deltaTime * seconds;
        }
    }
```

I want to move the Scroll View to the right from its current position to position `0, -1, 0`
Its current position when starting the game is: `-540, -1, 0`

What it does is move the Scroll View, but very fast and nonstop on the `X` and `Y` instead of only on the `X` and is not affected by the time; no matter if the seconds are 5 or 50, it will move too fast and nonstop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:
If you only want to affect one direction, then only affect changes on that axis.
transform.localPosition.x might be the ticket.

I'm really weak when it comes to determining how to slow things down, but I see a lot of gameObject examples where they implement a speed float that is always somewhere between 0f and 1f. Consider, instead of going by "number of seconds", you try a "move at this speed until the goal is reached"

Also, it may help to re-calculate difference during the Update method. Your position is different every frame, so the distance you need to travel is different every frame.

```
    void Update
{
//Possibly needs rethought
 if(transform.localPositon.x < end.x)
  {
     //Basic move me at a certain speed
     transform.localPosition.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;

     //You may also be able to use the difference variable to control the speed
     // speed * difference.x * Time.deltaTime;

     // Update Difference
       difference = end - transform.localPosition;
  }

}
```

You could even get fancy with this and try to implement a coroutine.

May not be perfect, but I hope this helps. Let me know if gets you closer to what your trying achieve.